# iframed jquery ui dialog not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, popup

I am showing iframe inside my jquery ui dialog. Inside dialog I am showing form for Add/Edit etc operations. I am using following HTML code:

```
@* This is container which is open as popup *@
<div id="dialog">
   <iframe frameborder="0" id="ContentIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS for this is:

```
#ContentIframe {
border: medium none;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
float:left;
}
```

and jquery code is like this:

```
/* This method opens iframed dialog box */
function ShowPopup(Url, DialogTitle, W, H) {

    /* Setting for dialog box */
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: DialogTitle,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: W,
        height: H,
        open: function (ev, ui) {
           /* Setting URL to open in iframe */
           $('#ContentIframe').attr('src', Url);
        }
    });

    /* Opening dialog box */
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

When calling ShowPopup method I pass URL to open inside popup. This works great but issue is, When I open say URL-A then close popup and then try to open popup on same page with URL-B, previous URL-A's content displayed first and then after seconds new content of URL-B is displayed. I think it's opened in iframe so next URL taking time to load but why old(previous) URL's content still present there as I already closed popup.

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see your close function, my guess is that you are simply hiding the popup div and so as you say, the new url takes some time to load and so you are seeing the previous page until then.

Simplest solution is to set the iframe src to empty page when you close the popup:

```
$('#ContentIframe').attr('src', 'about:blank');
```

Or chain it when you open the document, this will set it to blank then immediately your new URL (but it is untested if it will be quick enough for you):

```
open: function (ev, ui) {
   $('#ContentIframe').attr('src', 'about:blank')
                      .attr('src', Url);
}
```